# Converting pandas step into something more readable

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that creates a dataframe and append a new column to it. This new column is a hash based on other column datas:

```
df['uniqueid'] = df[['column_a', 'column_b', ... 'column_x']].\
            apply(lambda x: ed.generate_unique_ids(                    
                [
                   x['column_a'],
                   x['column_b'],
                   ...
                   x['column_x']
                ]), axis=1)
```

Is possible to write this code on something more readable? I'm not sure how to improve readability.

Basically, I want to select a few columns and pass it to other function that will give me a hash based on those values.

I'm new to Python and pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a code review question, but you can improve performance and readability by iterating over the underlying list/arrays and passing them directly to your function inside a list comprehension.

```
cols = ['column_a', 'column_b', ... 'column_x']
df['unique_id'] = [ed.generate_unique_ids(r) for r in df[cols].values.tolist()]
```

Comment: Cool! Is not necessary to call `apply(lambda,axis)` using list comprehension?

Comment: No, because df[cols].values.tolist() already created a list of rows from the dataframe. The list comprehension, iterates over each row generating a unique id and saving it in a new column of the dataframe.

Comment: @placplacboom No, it is not needed.